# Converting Foxpro program to MySQL stored procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, visual-foxpro, foxpro, set-based

I am in a process on converting a legacy system to web app using Ruby on Rails and MySQL.

There are few places that I'm stuck at while converting the data layer to MySQL procedures.

Giving a scenario below;

```
FUNCTION first_function
SELE Table1
REPL Table1.SmaCode WITH SMA(code,HcPc,FromDate)
ENDFUNC

FUNCTION SMA
... Lot of conditions ...
Lookup(param1,param2) * Parameters are based on the conditions above
.. Lot more conditions ....
ENDFUNC

FUNCTION Lookup
temp = Output of select on Check table 
return temp
ENDFUNC
```

Here SMA is another function which has so many conditions and it also calls another function Lookup. In Lookup function it query a table named Checks, the parameter to Lookup is based on the SMA.

Please see the pastebin of the source code in disucssion, if you need more insight. http://pastebin.com/raw/Hvx3b8zN

How can I go and convert this kind of functions to MySQL procedures?

**Edit:**
I'm looking for insights on this from people who've already done these types of conversions, from procedure oriented languages to set based stored procedures to be exact.

Comment: Looking at the VFP code and what is available in writing MySQL sprocs I would think that leaving it in the data layer and doing it in Ruby would be a easier approach. Either way you need to just identify and document what the VFP code is doing and replicate it.

Comment: Forgot to mention that I've tried doing it in ruby. The problem is that when we load the data to ruby the memory footprint is high.

Comment: There is no automatic language converter or trick, you must write the code according to your business needs using MySQL syntax.

Comment: @IvanCachicatari My aim was to gather some ideas on converting a procedural language to set based MySQL query, didn't mean to sound as if I was requesting exact MySQL syntax, I apologize if my question was breeding confusion.

Comment: @Vizkrig Foxpro commands are based on current records and opened tables, I'm old school developer I used  vfp too, is hard to translate vfp code without sample data or before-after samples, some legacy procedures now can be solved with one single line depending on language.

Answer (score 1):

The commentators are all right and I upticked them all.  You have to actually write the code but it's not too hard once you get going.

The first thing I do is to examine my code and rewrite all the straightforward things like DELETE FOR .... into DELETE WHERE...

Then I look at my loops and think about how I can treat that data as a set. A lot of times, SCANs can be written as a regular query when you use appropriate JOIN conditions and WHERE conditions.  There are a lot of query tools like CASE and subqueries that let you get a lot done with very little code.  MySQL allows temporary tables and that can come in very useful.  Lookups can often be done with subqueries.

On occasions, I have to use FETCH and WHILE loops but I avoid that as much as possible because it is slow and SQL is set based.

Just get started on the easy stuff and you'll get the hang of it :)